# create a new phone book entry with out dialog box

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, visual-c++

I found `RasCreatePhonebookEntry` to create a phone book entry but in SDK its mentioned as

> "This function has been deprecated as of Windows Vista and its
>   functionality has been replaced by RasDialDlg"

So is there any other way to create a new phone book entry with out promting to the user which supports in all versions of Windows?

And if `RasCreatePhonebookEntry` itself can be used for all versions of windows to create a new phone book entry, how to set the value of "`Preferred COM port`" option using "`RASENTRY`" structure? I didnt find any parameter in `RASENTRY` STRUCTURE to set the preferred port..

I want to set the following parameters in phone book :

```
PreferredPort=COM31
PreferredDevice=Communications cable between two computers #5

MEDIA=serial
Port=COM10
Device=Communications cable between two computers #5
ConnectBPS=460800
```

How to set the above parameters programatically by creating a new entry in phone book.

**Update:**

Fianlly I created a Ras Phonebook using `RasGetEntryProperties` and `"RasSetEntryProperties"`, But the only problem I face here is `"DeviceName"` for `"RASEntry" structure`. It works only if I give DeviceName as `"Communications cable between two computers #13".`

I tried enumerating "RasEnumDevices" but am getting list of devices.

```
WAN Miniport (L2TP)
WAN Miniport (L2TP)
WAN Miniport (PPTP)
WAN Miniport (PPTP)
WAN Miniport (PPPOE)
Communications cable between two computers #14
Communications cable between two computers #13
```

How to choose my device from this?

Comment: some one please comment on my post for the posibilities..

Comment: I would use the deprecated function and the replacement function. I can tell you the suggested way to do this won't work on versions prior to Vista since `RasDialDlg` didn't exist in Windows XP. What have you tried I don't see a single line of code.  Once you post actual code I will take my downvote away.

Comment: Dear Sir, With out finding a right API how to code it. I didnt start yet. Please suggest me  how to achieve it.

Comment: can some one comment on this for few possibilities!!!!!!